# Declare vector size with expression from generate variable

Tags: verilog

So I am trying to declare a variable sized array based on a generate variable, but my linting tool SpyGlass complains about rule `BitOrder-ML` and gives the following error message:

> Declare 'Vector Size' bit order '[((1 << level) -1):0]' as per convention

This is the code that generates the problem:

```
genvar level;
localparam integer LEVELS = 3;
generate
   for (level=0; level<LEVELS; level=level+1) begin
      wire result[(1 << level)-1:0];
   end
endgenerate
```

Is SpyGlass sane here? Does it somehow think that the expression `(1 << level)-1` would generate to a negative value?

The synthesize completes without a problem when the error is waived.

Comment: what will be the result for `level == 0`? you will get the `result[-1:0]` i would not blame spyglass for that.

Comment: @Serge: No, (1 << 0) - 1 = 0

Comment: oops, your right. should have waked up first :-)

Answer (score 1):

first of all

1-you have syntax problem

wire result[(1 << level)-1:0]]; you should delete last ].

2-you should declare level as a genvar not integer! genvar level; is correct.

NOTE : [(2^level)-1:0]  is more regular than [(1 << level)-1:0]

Comment: Sorry, typos. Fixed the code. I can add that the code synthesize fine if i turb off linting of these lines.

Comment: I use ISE xilinx syntheses tool below code and it have no problem can U upload your full code to i check it?

Comment: It's the linting tool  spyglass and also nlint that has problem with the code. The code is fine otherwise and able to synth.